# change URL spelling/case on sharepoint library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a sharepoint library that was created by a user with a url like "/mysite/MyLIBrary"

I want to change the case of the URL to be correct so it reads "/mysite/MyLibrary"

I cannot figure out how to do this in the sharepoint designer.  Just renaming the library doesn't change the URL.

Comment: have you tried renaming it to something different then back with the proper-case?

Comment: Yes, I tried renaming the library to something totally different and then back to the name with proper case and it didn't change the URL.  The URL retains the improper case no matter what I do.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to select Document Library in SharePoint designer and Rename. This updates the Title of the list, not actual name.

After this you will also have to rename Library in "All Files" (Left-Botton in SharePoint Designer). Select the library, right-click and rename.

HTH!

Comment: I've renamed the library but this doesn't change the URL.

Comment: This was in two steps, renaming the library (for the title) then the folder. Works for me, thank you spt2432!

Answer (score 2):

Just go to a library trough 'All Site Content'. When inside the library choose on the ribbon 'Library' tab. Then select 'Open with Explorer'. That will open your SharePoint's library in Windows Explorer window. Navigate one folder up and you will see list of your libraries as folders. Rename required library's folder name as you want the URL to look like.

Answer (score 1):

You can goto "Site Actions-->Site Settings-->Look and Feel-->Navigation-->Navigation Editing and Sorting" to change its URL's case.

Comment: Under Site Settings, Look and Feel, I don't have a navigation section.

Comment: Please goto your "site collection feature" settings, enable the "publishing feature", then you'll have it. here is a post for reference [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/configure-navigation-items-on-the-site-navigation-settings-page-HA010118190.aspx)

Comment: It's "site actions-->site settings-->site collection administration-->site collection features" settings, enable the "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature, then you'll have the "navigation".

Comment: This changes only navigation link in left panel, not library location. Library still stay by old URL.