# Change of Sharepoint List URL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, designer

I am facing the issue with renaming the Sharepoint list in Sharepoint 2010. I have tried the option of renaming the list from the Sharepoint site collection using the title , it actually changes the list name in quick link bar but the URL/ URI of the Sharepoint list does not change.

Also have tried the option of renaming the Sharepoint list from the sharepoint designer 2010 but that also does not change the Sharepoint list URL.

Have tried all the option posted in the SO Blog with the article

[SO Link][1]

([Change SharePoint Library URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904944/change-sharepoint-library-url/34456862?noredirect=1#comment56655626_34456862))

But it still does not change the actual web address of the list, the change in name of the list happens without any error message so I expect that the web address URL should change without any issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SharePoint Uses an internal name for the List, in addition to the Display Name (Title), when you create the list.  If you create the list using the UI/Browser, then the Internal Name will be a variation of the Title (IE: have special characters for spaces in title, for example).  You can also create a list using the API and control what the list Internal Name is on List Creation.

Unfortunately, once a list has been created you cannot change the Internal Name.

The URL path to the list and list contents will use the Internal name used upon list creation.

I you want a different URL, consider a redirect solution, or look into SharePoint Alternate Access Mappings, or re-create the list with the new name.

I believe that David Drever's suggestion is just dependent on creating a different separate list.  The short answer to your question is that you can't change the Internal Name to your SharePoint List once it's been created.

Comment: Thanks David and Alex for your assistance, I will have to use the workaround of creating the new list and moving the contents only when there is actual need of processing the URL, as the user requirement is only to rename the list I think from the front-end perspective it is fine for now.

Comment: Actually, David might have had the right idea.  You can't change the internal name of the list, but there are workarounds to change the URL and the Rootfolder.MoveTo() is one of them: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/03/how-to-change-url-of-librarylist.html

Comment: Right.  If he wanted to change the internal name that can only be done with a new list.  Since he just wanted a new URL I provided the script to do that.

Comment: @Alex, you might be confusing internal names of fields with the "internal" names of lists. Internal field names cannot be changed, but there is nothing similarly magical about list names. The name of a list (that is, its url) can be changed using Windows Explorer to view the site. The folders that represent lists and libraries can be renamed by selecting them and pressing F2 to rename. This changes the list/library URLs accordingly. (The list name is distinct from the list title, which is changed from the SharePoint interface and does not affect the list URL.)

Answer (score 1):

You can change a list or library URL, as long as it has not passed the list view threshold (5000 by default), after which such operations are throttled.

Either open the list/library in Windows Explorer and rename the folder that represents the list or library, or you can open the site in SharePoint Designer, open the All Files navigation node (generally the bottom-most node), find your list/library and right-click it to rename it.

I usually just use Explorer View because it's quick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell.

In my environment I created a list called BadName

I ran the following commands in PowerShell and successfully renamed it to GoodName:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "<MySiteUrl>";
$spList = $spWeb.Lists["BadName"];
$spList.RootFolder.MoveTo("Lists/GoodName");
```

This moved the list to the new name.  It also renamed the List to match the name.